# Using a TensorFlow 2.1.0 model built in Python in Java TensorFlow 1.15 | No Operation named [input] in the Graph

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a model written in Python 3.7 using TensorFlow 2.1.0. and I am trying to use it in an Java application (using TensorFlow 1.4), however, the model is not accepting input.  I would guess that this is a compatibility issue, but the model successfully loads in Java.  I've tried to use `keras.Sequential` and `keras.Model`, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  I've seen `tf.placeholder` being used in TF v1, but understand the v2 replacement is `tf.keras.Input`.

Python:

```
#method1
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.Input(name='input', shape=(60,), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='output')
])
```

```
#method 2
inputs = tf.keras.Input(name='input', shape=(60,), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Java:

```
Session.Runner runner = session.runner();
runner.feed("input", Tensor.create(testData));        

List<Tensor<?>> tensors = runner.fetch("output").run();
System.out.println("Answer is: " + tensors.get(0).floatValue());
```

Exception:

```
2020-05-07 01:32:23.596732: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:311] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success. Took 50986 microseconds.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Operation named [input] in the Graph
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.operationByName(Session.java:380)
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.parseOutput(Session.java:389)
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.feed(Session.java:131)
    at com.treyyoder.smurge.ml.TensorFlowTest.main(TensorFlowTest.java:40)
```

**!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! UPDATE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

Per [@karl-lessard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5755485/karl-lessard)'s suggestion, I included `org.tensorflow:proto` to be able to inspect the `MetaGraphDef`

MetaGraphDef is ~15k lines, this was the useful bit:

```
node {
    name: "StatefulPartitionedCall"
    op: "StatefulPartitionedCall"
    input: "serving_default_input"
    input: "dense/kernel"
    input: "dense/bias"
    input: "dense_1/kernel"
    input: "dense_1/bias"
    input: "output/kernel"
    input: "output/bias"
    attr {
      key: "_gradient_op_type"
      value {
        s: "PartitionedCallUnused"
      }
    }
    attr {
      key: "f"
      value {
        func {
          name: "__inference_signature_wrapper_9526"
        }
      }
    }
    attr {
      key: "Tout"
      value {
        list {
          type: DT_FLOAT
        }
      }
    }
    attr {
      key: "config_proto"
      value {
        s: "\n\a\n\003CPU\020\001\n\a\n\003GPU\020\0012\005*\0010J\0008\001"
      }
    }
    attr {
      key: "_output_shapes"
      value {
        list {
          shape {
            dim {
              size: -1
            }
            dim {
              size: 3
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    attr {
      key: "Tin"
      value {
        list {
          type: DT_FLOAT
          type: DT_RESOURCE
          type: DT_RESOURCE
          type: DT_RESOURCE
          type: DT_RESOURCE
          type: DT_RESOURCE
          type: DT_RESOURCE
        }
      }
    }
  }

...

node {
    name: "serving_default_input"
    op: "Placeholder"
    attr {
      key: "shape"
      value {
        shape {
          dim {
            size: -1
          }
          dim {
            size: 60
          }
        }
      }
    }
    attr {
      key: "dtype"
      value {
        type: DT_FLOAT
      }
    }
    attr {
      key: "_output_shapes"
      value {
        list {
          shape {
            dim {
              size: -1
            }
            dim {
              size: 60
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

...

signature_def {
  key: "serving_default"
  value {
    inputs {
      key: "input"
      value {
        name: "serving_default_input:0"
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        tensor_shape {
          dim {
            size: -1
          }
          dim {
            size: 60
          }
        }
      }
    }
    outputs {
      key: "output"
      value {
        name: "StatefulPartitionedCall:0"
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        tensor_shape {
          dim {
            size: -1
          }
          dim {
            size: 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
    method_name: "tensorflow/serving/predict"
  }
}
```

I discovered the correct input `serving_default_input` and output `StatefulPartitionedCall`

Updated Java code:

```
float[] fa = //Data you are passing to your model

List<Tensor<?>> tensor = runner.feed("serving_default_input", Tensor.create(fa))
    .fetch("StatefulPartitionedCall").run();

Tensor<Float> t1 = tensor.get(0).expect(Float.class);
float[][] vector = t1.copyTo(new float[1][3]);
for (float[] f : vector) {
  for (float ff : f) {
    System.out.println("res: " + ff);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're working with Keras models, try using TensorFlow Lite. See the [bintray repo](https://bintray.com/google/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to retrieve those names dynamically from the model signatures and feed them to your model for inference.

To see in Java what is the list of inputs/outputs of your saved model, you can retrieve the `MetaGraphDef` from the `SavedModelBundle`, as explained here: [Tensorflow 2.0 & Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61228372/tensorflow-2-0-java-api/61232138#61232138). (you can also double-check using the `[saved_model_cli][1]` command line utility).

But be aware that there is a bug with TF2.x when it comes to functional models, where TF proceed to some undocumented name mangling when it encodes the inputs/outputs signatures, as described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32674).

In addition, you might want to take a look at the [next version of TF Java](https://github.com/tensorflow/java), which supports natively TF2.x versions but are only available as snapshots at the moment.